# Matrix equation involving a Hadamard product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

I'm trying to find out the solution to B for the following matrix equation:
$$
A^TM_1=A^T(AB\odot M_2)
$$
where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $n<m$.
$M_1, M_2\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ are not invertible and their diagonal entries equal to $0$, $\odot$ represents the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there's an efficient approach we can take in which we regard the columns of $B$ separately. Let $M^{(i)}$ denote the $i$th column of $M$; we have
$$
[A^T(AB\odot M_2)]^{(i)} = \\
A^T(AB \odot M_2)^{(i)} = \\
A^T([AB]^{(i)} \odot M_2^{(i)}) = \\
A^T(AB^{(i)} \odot M_2^{(i)}) = \\
A^T \operatorname{diag}(M_2^{(i)})AB^{(i)}.
$$
We can thus solve for the $i$th column of $B$ (for $i = 1,\dots,m$) by solving the equation
$$
[A^T \operatorname{diag}(M_2^{(i)})A]B^{(i)} = [A^TM_1]^{(i)}.
$$
For a vector $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $\operatorname{diag}(x)$ denotes the diagonal matrix
$$
\operatorname{diag}(x) = \pmatrix{x_1\\&\ddots \\ && x_n},
$$
where the "blank" entries are zeroes.

---

More generally, you could use [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) in order to write out matrix equations like this as a linear system over a vector with $m\cdot n $ entries. In particular, if we take vec to denote column-major vectorization, we have
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A^T(AB\odot M_2)) = \\
(I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{vec}(AB\odot M_2) = \\
(I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(M_2)) \operatorname{vec}(AB) = \\
(I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(M_2)) (I \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B).
$$
So, the vectorized form of $B$ can be solved for using the equation
$$
(I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(M_2)) (I \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B) = \operatorname{vec}(A^TM_1).
$$

Comment: Now I want to find solutions for matrices $A$ and $B$ in the following equations:
$$
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        (I\otimes A^T) \operatorname{vec}(M_1)  = (I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(M_2)) (I \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B)
\\
        (B\otimes I) \operatorname{vec}(M_1)  = (B\otimes I)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(M_2)) (B^T\otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(A)
    \end{matrix}
\right..
$$
However, I'm stuck on this step. We can get $\operatorname{vec}(B)$ in the first equation, but how to transform it into $(B\otimes I)$?

Comment: Here's [a link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683729/solve-matrix-equations-involving-vectorization-and-kronecker-product) to the full description of my question.