# Solve matrix equations involving vectorization and Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, kronecker-product, hadamard-product, vectorization

I want to find solutions for matrices $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ in the following equations:

$$
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        A^TM_1  = A^T(AB\odot M_2)
\\
        M_1B^T  = (AB\odot M_2) B^T
    \end{matrix} 
\right.,
$$
where $M_1,M_2\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ are known invertible matrices, and $\odot$ represents Hardamard product. Through [vectorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680859/matrix-equation-involving-a-hadamard-product) we can have the following equations:
$$
\left\{
    \begin{matrix}
        (I\otimes A^T) \operatorname{vec}(M_1)  = (I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(M_2)) (I \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B)
\\
        (B\otimes I) \operatorname{vec}(M_1)  = (B\otimes I)\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(M_2)) (B^T\otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(A)
    \end{matrix}
\right.,
$$
where $\otimes$ represents [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), $\operatorname{diag}()$
denotes the diagonal matrix.
However, I'm stuck on this step. We get $\operatorname{vec}(B)$ in the first equation, but how to transform it into $(B\otimes I)$?

Comment: Combine the equations
$$\eqalign{
&(AB\odot M_2) = M_1 \\
&AB = (M_1\oslash M_2) \\
}$$
now pick any method (LU, QR, etc) to find acceptable factors $A,B$

Comment: @greg Well, $A$ is not a square matrix, so I don't think you can simply remove the $A^T$ on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, reduce the two equations to a single equation
$$AB \;=\; C \;=\; (M_1\oslash M_2)$$
To solve this equation, randomly initialize $B\:$ then iterate using alternating pseudoinverses
$$\eqalign{
&B \;\;= &B_0 \\
&k \;\;= &0 \\
&{\rm repeat} \\
&&A_{k+1} = CB_k^+ \\
&&B_{k+1} = A_{k+1}^+C \\
&&k = k+{\tt1} \\
&{\rm until}&\|C-A_kB_k\| \le 10^{-12} \\
}$$
If $m\le n$ this will converge in a single iteration
(**assuming** that a solution exists).

Each $B_0$ usually leads to a different solution.

Since $AB=(AZ)(Z^{-1}B)$ for any invertible $Z$, an infinite number of solutions are possible.